# docker container giving azure authentication error

Tags: azure, docker

I am trying to run a docker container for an app that I am working on. The container is on a company machine and at times it simply ceases to work and gives the error below. Can anyone explain to me why azure would be involved or what is happening here?

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Head https://{docker container url}/{tag}: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
```

If I try to build the image to run it locally, I get the following error on build:

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for {company URL}/alpine-3.12-base:0.2.0                                                                                                                0.8s
```

---

> [internal] load metadata for {company URL}/alpine-3.12-base:0.2.0:

---

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: What Azure Service do you use and please share the documentation that you follow to deploy the container.

Comment: Have you logged in to the docker registry where you are pulling the image from?